# Always return false in python outright, it is true

Tags: python

I am writing a program in python  that take some string and test it through some condition

1. the first 2 characters in the sting must be letters

2 . the steer must be maximum of 6 characters and at least 2 characters

3 . Numbers cannot be used in the middle of the string; they must come at the end. For example, AAA222 would be an acceptable … ; AAA22A would not be acceptable

4 . The first number used cannot be a ‘0’.”

5 . [' ', ',', ';', '-', '_'] thos characters are not allowed

this is my code so far

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    total = is_N_1(s) + is_N_2(s) + is_N_3(s) + is_N_4(s) + is_N_5(s)
    if total  == 5:
        #print (total)
        return True
    else:
        #print(total)
        return False


def is_N_1(s):
    if len(s)<7 and len(s)>3:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def is_N_2(s):
    if s[0:2].isalpha():
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def is_N_3(s):
    for i in s:
        if s[-1].isalpha() and i.isnumeric():
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

def is_N_4(s):
    t = []
    for i in s:
        if i.isdigit():
            t.append(i)

    if len(t)<=0:
        return 1
    else:
        if t[0] == '0':
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

def is_N_5(s):
    not_allow =[' ', ',', ';', '-', '_']
    for i in s :
        for _ in not_allow :
            if i == _:
                return 1
            else :
                return 0
main()
```

this is the input that give an error in the output

```
1 . input of "CS50" 
    expected "Valid", not "Invalid\n"

2 . input of "ECTO88"
    expected "Valid", not "Invalid\n"

3 . input of "NRVOUS"
    expected "Valid", not "Invalid\n"
```

can any one take a look at this and tell me what I did wrong, I stack for 2 hours and I did not find the solution?

Comment: Show us what input you're giving the program, and what output it produces.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal test case in which your script produces wrong output?

Comment: fixed by Desty and  @Piotr-Grzybowski thank you for both of you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is how to check the string in s one by one for not allowed characters within not_allow. I think that just fixing this part will solve it.

```
def is_N_5(s):
    not_allow =[' ', ',', ';', '-', '_']
    for i in s :
        if i in not_allow:
            return 0
    return 1
```

Comment: This is not true.  Underscore is a CONVENTION used to ignore values, but underscore is a perfectly valid identifier.  This is not the cause of his trouble.

Comment: This is completely not true, _ is fine python variable name.

Answer (score 2):

In the 5th condition, you should reverse the return values. Now you return 1 when one of not allowed chars is used.

```
def is_N_5(s):
    not_allowed = [' ', ',', ';', '-', '_']
    for i in s: 
        if i in not_allowed:
            return 0
     return 1
```

Comment: Yes, this is PART of the problem.  The other part is that he can't return "1" until he knows that ALL of the characters are OK.  Right now, it will only check that the first character is not a space.  He must delete the "else", and add "return 1" at the end of the function after both loops complete.

Answer (score 1):

Your function **is_N_5** has an invalid reference.
**not_allwo** should be updated to **not_allow**

```
def is_N_5(s):
    not_allow =[' ', ',', ';', '-', '_']
    for i in s :
        for _ in not_allow :
            if i == _:
                return 1
            else :
                return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method srt.isalum() in function
is_N_5

if s.isalum():   return
els